# Combine similar data for entities

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a query that can present the quantities instead of the data in its simplified form. I'm presenting my problem with a basic example because I'm playing with tons of records.

As shown in the basic output from the Temp table, I'm working towards presenting the 2nd & 3rd columns with respective to the actual value count. I'm trying to query the temp table further to present Department along with the count of each operating systems used in the dept and also the count of Tech_Company.

I have tried the following query to present unique Departments and the associated count under each items towards right but I'm getting duplicate entries because of difference in the right side columns.

```
/************ Table Creation ****************/
CREATE TABLE #TEMP1 
(
    Department VARCHAR(20),
    Operating_System VARCHAR(20),
    Tech_Company VARCHAR(20) 
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP1 VALUES 
('Marketing','Windows','DellLaptop'),
('Sales','IOS','Macbook'),
('Financial','IOS','Macbook'),
('Human Resources','Andorid','DellLaptop'),
('Human Resources','Andorid','DellLaptop'),
('Human Resources','Andorid','Lenovo'),
('PR','IOS','Macbook'),
('Buying','Windows','HP'),
('Buying','Linux','Asus'),
('Buying','Windows','Asus'),
('Buying','Linux','DellLaptop'),
('R&D','Linux', 'DellLaptop')
GO

/************ End of Table Creation ****************/
SELECT * FROM #TEMP1

DROP TABLE #TEMP1

Basic Output:

Department  Operating_System    Tech_Company
Marketing        Windows          DellLaptop
Sales              IOS             Macbook
Financial          IOS             Macbook
Human Resources    Andorid        DellLaptop
Human Resources    Andorid        DellLaptop
Human Resources    Andorid         Lenovo
PR                 IOS            Macbook
Buying             Windows          HP
Buying             Linux          Asus
Buying             Windows        Asus
Buying             Linux          DellLaptop
R&D                Linux          DellLaptop
```

What I have tried:

```
SELECT Department, case when Operating_System = 'Windows' THEN COUNT(Department) ELSE '' END AS 'Windows',
                   case when Operating_System = 'IOS' THEN COUNT(Department) ELSE '' END AS 'IOS',
                   case when Operating_System = 'Andorid' THEN COUNT(Department) ELSE '' END AS 'Andorid',
                   case when Operating_System = 'Linux' THEN COUNT(Department) ELSE '' END AS 'Linux',
                   case when Tech_Company = 'DellLaptop' THEN COUNT(Department) ELSE '' END AS 'DellLaptop',
                   case when Tech_Company = 'Macbook' THEN COUNT(Department) ELSE '' END AS 'Macbook',
                   case when Tech_Company = 'HP' THEN COUNT(Department) ELSE '' END AS 'HP',
                   case when Tech_Company = 'Lenovo' THEN COUNT(Department) ELSE '' END AS 'Lenovo',
                   case when Tech_Company = 'Asus' THEN COUNT(Department) ELSE '' END AS 'Asus'
FROM #TEMP1
GROUP BY Department,Operating_System,Tech_Company

Output: 
Department      Windows IOS Andorid Linux DellLaptop Macbook HP Lenovo Asus
Buying             0     0     0      1        0        0    0     0    1
Buying             0     0     0      1        1        0    0     0    0
Buying             1     0     0      0        0        0    0     0    1
Buying             1     0     0      0        0        0    1     0    0
Financial          0     1     0      0        0        1    0     0    0
Human Resources    0     0     2      0        2        0    0     0    0
Human Resources    0     0     1      0        0        0    0     1    0
Marketing          1     0     0      0        1        0    0     0    0
PR                 0     1     0      0        0        1    0     0    0
R&D                0     0     0      1        1        0    0     0    0
Sales              0     1     0      0        0        1    0     0    0
```

New Schema should be as follows:

```
    Col 1    Col 2   Col 3   Col 4   Col 5   Col 6   Col 7    Col8  Col9 Col10
Department  Windows   IOS   Andorid  Linux  DellLap Macbook  Lenovo   HP  Asus
  Buying       2       0       0       2       1       0        0      1    2 
 Financial     0       1       0       0       0       1        0      0    0
 Human Res     0       0       3       0       2       0        1      0    0 
 Marketing     1       0       0       0       1       0        0      0    0
    PR         0       1       0       0       0       1        0      0    0
    R&D        0       0       0       1       1       0        0      0    0
   Sales       0       1       0       0       0       1        0      0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you just need a basic pivot query here:

```
SELECT
    Department,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Operating_System = 'Windows' THEN 1 END) AS Windows,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Operating_System = 'IOS' THEN 1 END) AS Windows,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Operating_System = 'Android' THEN 1 END) AS Android,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Operating_System = 'Linux' THEN 1 END) AS Linux,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Tech_Company = 'DellLaptop' THEN 1 END) AS DellLaptop,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Tech_Company = 'Macbook' THEN 1 END) AS Macbook,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Tech_Company = 'Lenovo' THEN 1 END) AS Lenovo,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Tech_Company = 'HP' THEN 1 END) AS HP,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Tech_Company = 'Asus' THEN 1 END) AS Asus
FROM #TEMP1
GROUP BY
    Department;
```